# NetBeans Platform app with Maven: Menu item "Open Project..." is missing

Tags: maven, menuitem, netbeans-platform

Using Ant, I've built a NetBeans platform app which enables the user to open a custom project type. Now I try to do the same using Maven. The Maven project builds and runs, but the Open Project menu item is missing.

I've examined the list of jar files included in the distribution of the Ant project and ensured that all these files are present in the Maven project's list of dependencies. I expected the two programs to be equal. I'm using NetBeans 20 and JDK21, but I had the same problem also using JDK1.8.
What is missing?